# How do I fix a custom border when dragging a form off the screen and back on?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a code to draw a custom dashed border around my textboxes and forms. If I grab the app and drag it off the screen and come back the border is all smeared and bad looking.

The only way I've been able to fix it is by using Me.Reload() event making the form reload which fixes it immediately. Which is alright but I'd rather it be fixed immediately almost to the point that you never even see it happen.

When I tried to add it into a timer it made the form blink really bad obviously.

[image]

Is there a way to use this code to detect when the app leaves the boundaries of the screen and just refresh the form only when the whole app returns within the boundaries of the monitor or monitors?

```
Public Function IsOnScreen(ByVal form As Form) As Boolean
    Dim screens() As Screen = Screen.AllScreens

    For Each scrn As Screen In screens
        Dim formRectangle As Rectangle = New Rectangle(form.Left, form.Top, form.Width, form.Height)

        If scrn.WorkingArea.Contains(formRectangle) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```

EDIT: I wanted to share the code I'm using to draw these borders in case it may actually be the issue.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    ' This is the override paint event that will allow us to draw all our borders
    addBorders(e)
End Sub

    Public Sub addBorders(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf (ctl) Is TextBox
            ctl.AutoSize = False
            ctl.Height = 19
            Dim borderRectangle As Rectangle = New Rectangle(ctl.Location, ctl.Size)
            borderRectangle.Inflate(1, 1)
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, borderRectangle, ctl.ForeColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Dashed)
        Case TypeOf (ctl) Is ComboBox, TypeOf (ctl) Is Button
            Dim borderRectangle As Rectangle = New Rectangle(ctl.Location, ctl.Size)
            borderRectangle.Inflate(1, 1)
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, borderRectangle, ctl.ForeColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Dashed)
 >>>ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, ctl.ForeColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Dashed)<<< This is the problem!
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

I've tried adding TypeOf (ctl) Is Form to the second Case and that does not work and I am not sure why!

```
Case TypeOf (ctl) Is ComboBox, TypeOf (ctl) Is Button, TypeOf (ctl) Is Form
```

This code works perfect for the comboboxes and the textboxes but it does not draw the border on the form.

Comment: Don't use ClipRectangle. I don't see you clearing the canvas: `e.Graphics.Clear(Me.BackColor)`.  Make sure you have the form's DoubleBuffered and ResizeRedraw properties set to true.  The form is not a part of the Controls collection.  I don't see any code that draws your screen shot.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by drawing a screen shot. I'll see if I can research this. DoubleBuffered is set to true now but I don't see a property called ResizeRedraw.

Comment: The green thingy image.  ResizeRedraw isn't in the designer.  You would have to set it yourself in the form's constructor:  `Me.ResizeRedraw = True`

Comment: Oh the screenshot that I have up. That's just a screenshot I took of it drawing a ton of borders across the top of my app when I drag the app back on the screen. I've fixed this problem by removing the line with the >>> on it. The issue I'm having now is I can't figure out how to draw the border back around the outside of the form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question because I've finally got it working.

First of all I changed how I was drawing the border around the form.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    ' This is the override paint event that will allow us to draw all our borders
    addBorders(e)
    If e.ClipRectangle.X = 0 Then
        Dim dashValues As Single() = {3, 1, 3, 1}
        Dim p As New Pen(btnExit.ForeColor, 1)
        p.DashPattern = dashValues
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, Me.Width - 1, Me.Height - 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Which worked perfect! There was still a small issue with going off the screen it would still mess the border up some so I added a Me.Refresh() code on the form_mouseup event so when the form is dropped it refreshes and fixes the problem.

```
Private Sub frmMain_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

It's not exactly what I would have liked to have but it works way better this way than the other way.

Comment: It's ridiculous that after posting this question 3 different times and listening to a bunch of whiny mods on this website that I ended up having to fix my code myself because all the self righteous wanna be coders on this website couldn't notice one line of code that was causing my problems. Instead they would rather sit around whining in comments.